# Understanding fragments

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

I've just started working with fragment shaders and after I've done some simple plasma effects I got stuck. I already know that you can retrieve a fragment's X, Y and Z and I was thinking of building a shader that will colour fragments according to their Z.

Here's what I have so far:

```
void main() {
    float z = gl_FragCoord.z;
    float t = (sin(z) + 1) * 0.5;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(t, t, t, 1);
}
```

The problem is that I'm testing this with a triangle and no matter how I rotate it, it has the same constant colour so I'm starting to ask myself (and on SO): Why is the triangle of one single colour? Isn't this Z supposed to be per fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z coordinate in the gl_FragCoord is normalised between 0 and 1 (where 0 correspond to the near-plane and the 1 correspond to the far-plane). Using perspective projection, this mapping is non-linear in favour of the near-plane. This means that it is likely that your triangle will map to the same color even when rotated.

It is worth pointing out that your general idea works just fine (created in my GLSL shader editor):
http://goo.gl/32Voo

Note that I here use orthogonale projection to get a better depth visualisation - switching to projection makes the color almost identical (only varies a few percentage).

Comment: Note that you can also reconstruct camera-space Z-values from perspectively projected depth values fairly easily, by applying the inverse of the projection matrix (which can in turn be done for must cheaper than a full matrix multiply because of all the zero terms in a perspective projection matrix). That way your triangle will still be perspectively correct, but you can color based on linear Z values.